# Scroll Depth Tracking in React SPA with Google Tag Manager

Tags: scroll, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I'm currently working on a React single-page application (SPA) and trying to implement scroll depth tracking using Google Tag Manager (GTM). However, I've encountered an issue where the scroll event is being triggered automatically upon page load, even before any user scrolling activity occurs.

I've attempted several solutions, including scripts from [Lunametrics](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/09/27/scroll-tracking-recipe-gtm), [MarekLecian](https://mareklecian.cz/en/gtm-script-for-measuring-scrolling-in-single-page-applications/), and [JSNDesign](https://jsndesign.co.uk/blog/scroll-depth-tracking-google-tag-manager-implementation/), but none of them seem to resolve the issue. The problem persists, and I need guidance on how to track scroll events accurately in the SPA.

Here are some relevant details about my setup:

- Google Tag Manager is integrated into the page.
- We are currently using the out-of-the-box triggers for tracking
  scroll depth (these are the ones that are failing)

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with React SPAs and GTM scroll tracking? If so, what alternative solutions or configurations can I explore to ensure that the scroll tracking events are only triggered when users genuinely scroll through the page?

Thanks.